# c# use specific process handle for accessing remote process

Tags: c#, inheritance, handle

I inherit a handle to a process and would like to be able to use the functions in the Process class that C# gives me through System.Diagnostics however I can't find any way to specify the handle to use, initializing a Process from System.Diagnostics seems to open a new handle to it.

(I get a privileged handle from an elevated process to a non elevated one so creating a new handle with the right access type is unfortunately not possible in this scenario)

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried querying for the existing process via `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses().Where(...)`?

Comment: I've already tried adding it by id but that doesn't solve the fact that it spawns a new handle to the process instead of using the exiting one.
I have the pointer to the handle but I doubt c# has a way to open a process by the handle or I haven't seen one yet.